# POS dynamic item capital

Tags: database, erd, financial

I've try to search this, but I haven't found it yet.
I have a case of payment online system.

Let's say I have an item named "A"
"A" stocks is 30
but, from the "A" stocks.. 
I buy 20 of "A" for $10 each from supplier
and the rest 10 of "A", I buy $15 each from supplier
and then I sell "A" $20 each

Now, How do I design the item table in the database for "A" so I able to count 
the exact profit for "A"

am I have to input 2 row in "item" table which contain
"A.1" for $10 of capital and
"A.2" for $15 of capital

If that's the conclusion, that means..
When a customer buy "A" 25 pieces.
Then I have to decrease A.1 stock to 0
and A.2 to 5

Are you guys have a better solution from me ?
Sorry for my bad English and knowledge.

Comment: A lot of your design will depend on how advanced you want the application to be. For a simple app you can store the purchase price in item, but since it will vary over time that's not a flexible design. You'll need a purchase history table if you really want to go for that.

Comment: I agree with the history table.I wonder how the big retail company do this stuff, are they use static prize or history table like you said. I don't know, I'm a newbie, but I've try to search this, everyone use static buy prize. anyway, thx for ur answer.

Comment: Big retail companies use a purchase order system.

Comment: would you mind give me a short detail of purchase order system, I mean the ERD ?, pls